# Is it possible to disable syntax highlighting for .txt files in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I'd like to disable syntax highlighting and enable (if possible) soft wrapping for .txt files in Gitlab. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable syntax highlight: seems not: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8404

Similar problem for code blocks in markdown: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6571399-don-t-guess-rendered-code-block-filetype-and-rende

Soft wrapping: not possible. It has been recently implemented for merge requests: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/5004385-wrap-lines-option-in-the-merge-request but was not well factored enough to also apply to isolated blobs.

I recommend opening feature requests at: http://feedback.gitlab.com for both.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and for your suggestion! I'll do that.