# what does red and bold text mean in a gitlab commit?

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, color-scheme

I'm using Gitlab to examine commits that I and other people have made in a repository. Gitlab displays a commit as shown in the image. It highlights added lines with a green background and deleted lines with a red background.  But some lines appear with red text. What does this mean?  And other words appear in bold black.  What do this mean?

[image]

Comment: I suspect it to be a markdown file with red, bold text present in the markdown syntax itself. Please check.

Comment: Sorry Venkataraman, I don't understand your comment?  It is not a markdown file, it is a LaTeX file with a .ltx extension.     Whom are you asking to check?  And what are you asking him to check?

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned you in the comment. I get your point. Is the latex file itself, wants to display the text in red, bold text ? because, just red highlight (removed text), green highlight(added text) comes from gitlab. Other parts could be from the file itself, in this case, I feel. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Venkatarama,  no, the LaTeX code is must text, there are no colorization instructions in there.      I wish I could turn off this annoying feature of GitLab, but I don't find a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/highlighting.html

> GitLab provides syntax highlighting on all files and snippets through
>   the Rouge rubygem. It will try to guess what language to use based on
>   the file extension, which most of the time is sufficient.

also

> If GitLab is guessing wrong, you can override its choice of language
>   using the gitlab-language attribute in .gitattributes.

**So Gitlab might have guessed the syntax wrong.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  But If I add a .gitattributes file, it will be at the head of the tree, will this or should this have an effect on the entire history?

Can I ask GitHub which language it has guessed the file is?

Comment: Adding .gitattributes file will not affect the file's history.

Comment: So if adding a .gitattributes file at commit X will not effect how commits before X are highlighted, is there a way that I can turn off syntax highlighting and maintain only difference highlighting.  I don't see how syntax highlighting is useful for looking at diffs anyway.  At worst syntax highlighting can be misleading, leading me to believe that something has changed in the particular commit which hasn't changed.

Comment: I think Gitlab currently doesn't support LaTeX syntax highlights.

Comment: So the documentation for Rouge lists TeX as a supported language.  But does not however, mean that the user wants too see attempted language highlighting.

Comment: There's no way to turn syntax highlighting off. I stumbled upon this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304769/is-it-possible-to-disable-syntax-highlighting-for-txt-files-in-gitlab.

Comment: Did my answer satisfy your original question - _what does red and bold text mean in a gitlab commit?_

Comment: Yes, I understand now.  Thanks.